# How do I order my table by the date entered by user

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, sql-order-by

This is the code for my table:

```
<table border="black">
    <tr><th>Date</th><th>Newsletter ID</th></tr>


        <?php
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)):
        echo "<tr><td>" . htmlentities($row["DATE_ENG"]) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . htmlentities($row["FEATURE_TITLE_ENG"]) . "</td>";
        $NewsIDN = $row["NEWS_IDN"];
        ?>
        <td>
        <form name="editEmail" action="editEmail.php" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="EmailID" value="<?php echo $NewsIDN; ?>"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="e"> 
            <input type="submit" name="editEmail" value="Edit"/>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form name="deleteEmail" action="deleteEmail.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="newsIDN" value="<?php echo $NewsIDN; ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name="deleteEmail" value="Delete" action="deleteEmail.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete')"/>
        </form>



    </td>
```

This is the query that is taking in the data. How do I make it so that it orders the table from top to bottom by the correct date so that january 2013 is before may 2013?

```
public function get_Newsletters() {
$query = "SELECT         NEWS_IDN,DATE_ENG,DATE_FRA,FEATURE_TITLE_ENG,FEATURE_TITLE_FRA,FEATURE_DESC_ENG,FEATURE_DESC_FRA,FEATURE_IMG_URL_ENG,FEATURE_IMG_URL_FRA,FEATURE_IMG_ALT_ENG,FEATURE_IMG_ALT_FRA,FEATURE_URL_ENG,FEATURE_URL_FRA,LAST_MODIFIED_BY,LAST_MODIFIED_DT,PUBLISHED_IND FROM BETS.TB__BETS_NEWSLETTERS ORDER BY DATE_ENG";
$stid = oci_parse($this->con, $query);
oci_execute($stid);
return $stid;
}
```

So the table is calling the above query and right now I am just doing ORBEDER BY DATE_ENG

Comment: What format is the date stored in?

Comment: what is the type of `DATE_ENG` column

Comment: The date is just a string it actualy can just be entered in as any word whatso ever

Comment: example I have some entires with date such as April 19 1993 and then some of just plain text as test or example

Comment: What data type have you used for `DATE_ENG`in your table? This will only work if its a DATETIME column.

Comment: I just need the query to order it so it checks the month then day then year

Comment: @KyleWatson How can you expect to sort anything if you don't know what format it's in?

Comment: okay sorry what do you mean by what format it is in?

Comment: @KyleWatson You're taking the date as a free format string. Look at this example: 04/12/2012. Is that 4th December 2012 or 12th April 2012? What about 2012-04-12 or 12th April 2012 or April 12, 2012? To sort these you need to have the date in a consistent format.

Comment: oh okay I just have the DATE_ENG as a varchar string

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL's default sort order is ASC, meaning the rows are ordered from the lowest to highest, in date values this becomes from early time to late time.

You are using "order by DATE_ENG ASC" and that will sort the dates from small to big. And what you want should be accomplished by that.

If it is the other way around, try " order by DATE_ENG DESC"

If your DATE_ENG is type of varchar, then sorting is done alpebetically and depending on format of your dates, may not be as what you wanted to be.

Best usage is, for date fields always use unix TIMESTAMP or DATETIME, then using "order by" statement always gives you the correct results.

The advantage of this approach is that almost every language have tools to deal with unix TIMESTAMPs and mysql DATETIME formats by default.

Comment: I did the ASC but it makes Dec 31 1999 come before May 12 2012..?

Comment: ASC is the default, if your mysql column type is DATETIME then use DESC, that makes later dates come first. And I updated my answer, reading it again may help.

Comment: oh so I need to chnage the column type in my DB to DATETIME?

Comment: If you store dates in type of DATETIME, it will be more precise and easy to sort and handle. What is your current DATE_ENG field type?

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_ENG` should be a `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type. Without that, it can't be accurately sorted. Once you change that around, you're able to insert the date into the database by using [`now()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now). You can then order properly by `ORDER BY DATE_ENG` or `ORDER BY DATE_ENG DESC`

Check out [**more information**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) on the `datetime` data types.

Comment: oh okay yeah it is just a string data type not a Date or anything that is my problem

Comment: Exactly! It should't be a string. Change it up and your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This will `order by` results if the date stored in column in this format `m/d/Y` if your format is different then use that specific date format in the `STR_TO_DATE` function

```
SELECT NEWS_IDN,DATE_ENG,DATE_FRA,FEATURE_TITLE_ENG,FEATURE_TITLE_FRA,
FEATURE_DESC_ENG,FEATURE_DESC_FRA,FEATURE_IMG_URL_ENG,FEATURE_IMG_URL_FRA,
FEATURE_IMG_ALT_ENG,FEATURE_IMG_ALT_FRA,FEATURE_URL_ENG,FEATURE_URL_FRA,
LAST_MODIFIED_BY,LAST_MODIFIED_DT,PUBLISHED_IND FROM BETS.TB__BETS_NEWSLETTERS
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DATE_ENG, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC
```

Here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fb05/1) for some column but to show you how it works even if your column type is not date

Comment: hey I did that but I dont have an identifer STR_TO_DATE

Comment: it is a mysql function and if your column type not date it will treat as date

Comment: If you're early on in your development phase I'd highly recommend you changing the data type to `DATE` or `DATETIME`. It will save you from tons of issues down the road. It's terrible practice to store a date as a string.